# Is it possible to get the request headers in a request?

Tags: javascript, webrequest

Title pretty much sums it up, I am trying to intercept a web request and get the request headers.

This is what I tried:

```
let oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send    
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    console.log(this.responseHeaders);
    return oldSend.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

This is what I expect:

```
{"test":"abcd1234"}
```

Comment: Are you after _request_ or _response_ headers?

Comment: @Phil I am trying to get request headers.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't expose them. Your only option is to hijack `setRequestHeader()` and capture them there

Comment: @Phil Didn't think about that! Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS/jQuery get HTTPRequest request headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10515862/283366)

Answer (score -1):

on PHP

```
<?php
header('Test 123 I Love Bacon'); // just to test header_ list

var_dump(headers_list()); // show headers to be sent by the browser
?>
```